# QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent is not called

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

When I click on my scene - nothing happens. I tried many various methods with `QMouseEvent` and `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`, tried to set focus on my object and then try to click on it - with no result. I was also looking for solution on the Internet on posts from other people, but didn't found anything that would work for me. Where I make mistakes?

Here is some code below:

This is one of my windows, where I create scene, view and object - that I want make respond on my mouse events:

```
TrackWindow::TrackWindow(Timers *timer)
{
timeLineBar = new QGraphicsScene(this);
timeLineBarView = new QGraphicsView(timeLineBar);
timeLineBarView->setFixedHeight(20);
timeLineBarView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);
timeLineBarView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
timeLineBarView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
timeLineBarView->setStyleSheet("background-color: #333333; border:none;");

QVBoxLayout *timeLineLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
timeLineLayout->addWidget(timeLineBarView);
timeLineLayout->addWidget(tracksTimelineView);
timeline = new TimeLine(timer);
timeLineBar->addItem(timeline);
//timeline->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
//timeline->setFocus();
}
```

Here is my Timeline class implementation:

```
TimeLine::TimeLine(Timers *t)
{
    timer = new Timers;
    timer = t;
    timeLineWidth = 200000;
    timeLineScale = 0.1;
}

QRectF TimeLine::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,timeLineWidth,18);
}

void TimeLine::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();

    QPen pen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(QColor(200,200,200));
    painter->drawRect(rect);

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        painter->drawText(i*30,9,QString::number(i+1));
    }

}

void TimeLine::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        timer->start();
    }
}
```

And header of my class:

```
#ifndef TIMELINE_H
#define TIMELINE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QColor>
#include <QRect>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include "timers.h"

class TimeLine: public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    TimeLine(Timers *t);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget);

    float timeLineScale;
    int timeLineWidth;
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);

private:
    Timers *timer;

protected:

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);


};

#endif // TRACK_H
```

Comment: Try _QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent_ instead

Comment: I don't know how to use your solution in my example.

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to do when you can get the mouse event? QGraphicsItem has several actions that are handled differently.

Comment: I want to start my timer, when mouse button is pressed. There is line: 'timer->start();' that starts timer. I would like that when I click anywhere on my timeline, perform an action.

Comment: Your scene is shown in a QGraphicsView, right? Reimplement _QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent_ starting the timer as you want.

Comment: @Lizard_Paszczyk Check my answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by overwriting the `boundingRect()` method, how are you inheriting from `QGraphicsRectItem` it is correct to use `setRect()`

**timeline.h**

```
#ifndef TIMELINE_H
#define TIMELINE_H

#include "timers.h"
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class TimeLine : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    TimeLine(Timers *t, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
private:
    int timeLineWidth;
    float timeLineScale;
    Timers *timer;
};

#endif // TIMELINE_H
```

**timeline.cpp**

```
#include "timeline.h"

#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>

TimeLine::TimeLine(Timers *t, QGraphicsItem *parent):QGraphicsRectItem(parent)
{
    timer = t;
    timeLineWidth=200000;
    setRect(QRectF(0,0,timeLineWidth,18));
    timeLineScale = 0.1;

}

void TimeLine::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option)
    Q_UNUSED(widget)
    QRectF rect = boundingRect().toRect();

    QPen pen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(QColor(200,200,200));
    painter->drawRect(rect);

    painter->setPen(Qt::red);
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        painter->drawText(i*30,9,QString::number(i+1));
    }
}


void TimeLine::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        timer->start();
}
```

**Note:** it is not necessary to create a Timers inside TimeLine: `timer = new Timers`; since afterwards you are changing the direction of the pointer and therefore that space is unusable besides that it is unnecessary.

In the following [`link`](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47328152) you will find the project that you use to test the functionality.

Comment: Your solution is wonderful! Thank you very much for advices about pointer to my Timer. I also didn't know about Q_UNUSED() function - unused variables was anoying me. Please become my mentor ;]